# how to run xtend TestNg class?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, testng, xtext, xtend

here's Xtend class, I cannot seems to get eclipse to run configuration of this TestNg file I wrote on eclipse xtend. I installed TestNg Plugin as well, but still I don't see a option. How can I run it?

Does Xtend Plugin or TestNg plugin requires and modifications to support adding the run as configuration ? If so how may I add necessary changes?

MySampleTestng.xtend file

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test

class MySampleTestng {

    @Test
    def void testPrintln() {
        println("Hello, World.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the TestNG runner from the generated java source. In the Xtend editor open the context menu -> "Open generated File" and from there you can start TestNG. Once started you a run configuration will be added as for "normal" java test files.

Answer (score -1):

After you install the plugin you need to navigate to `Window -> Show View -> Other -> Java -> TestNG` select it to add it to the viewport. [Here](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html) are the Eclipse TestNG plugin docs, they should answer any more questions you have.